# Install not as root

Tags: apt, root

I currently have a process that does `sudo apt-get` on a large number of files, `sudo make install` and the like.

Is there a simple way to use these scripts when I do not have root access?

Answer (score 0):

## User APT

I am not familiar with a way to install deb's through apt for a normal user.  Many times, additional packages are required and some may need to be installed at root level to function normally.

## User MAKE

1. `mkdir ~/bin/`
2. `echo "PATH=${PATH}:/home/USER/bin >> ~/.bashrc`
3. ./configure --prefix=/home/USER/bin
4. make --prefix=/home/USER/bin
5. make install

This creates a directory in your home directory called **bin**.  It then adds that directory to the list of locations the system will check for a binary.  The last three steps are configuring/compiling/installing the source to your user's bin directory.